# CToolTipCtrl or CMFCToolTipCtrl does not work with combo boxes

Tags: c++, mfc

The documented way of adding a tooltip:

```
pToolTip->AddTool(pControl,...);
...
BOOL ...::PreTranslateMessage(..)
{
    ...
        pToolTip->RelayEvent(..);
    ...
}
```

does not work with combo boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Shrid's tip (originally from David Lowndes) is to replace in PreTranslateMessage(..)

```
pToolTip->RelayEvent(pMsg);
```

with

```
MSG stMsg = *pMsg;
stMsg.hwnd = (HWND)m_pToolTip->SendMessage(TTM_WINDOWFROMPOINT, 0, (LPARAM)&stMsg.pt);
CPoint cPnt = pMsg->pt;
if (stMsg.message >= WM_MOUSEFIRST && stMsg.message <= WM_MOUSELAST)
    ::ScreenToClient(stMsg.hwnd, &cPnt);
stMsg.lParam = MAKELONG(cPnt.x, cPnt.y);
m_pToolTip->RelayEvent(&stMsg);
```